# Date output for tenth of seconds?

Tags: php, date, php-5.5

I'm storing laptimes in a database in the following format: 103.900.

I'm outputting time from the database by using the following date format:

```
date('i:s.U', $video->best_lap)
```

What i get back is: 01:43.103.  The actual output time should display 01:43.900.  Is there someway I can make PHP play nicely?

Comment: From the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php): `Note:
Since this function only accepts integer timestamps the u format character is only useful when using the date_format() function with user based timestamps created with date_create().` Consider using DateTime and its `format()` method instead

Comment: Thanks Mark but i'm not sure how that helps? @Mark

Comment: For something like this I would suggest storing the time in tenths of a second and then converting either when or after pull it from the database.

Comment: Here's how it helps: `$dto = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', '103.900');
var_dump($dto->format('i:s.u'));`

Comment: @Mark can you please submit that as an answer so I can give you credit?  That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's date functions (using unix timestamps, which are integer values) don't support fractional seconds (as described in the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php))

> **Note:**
>   Since this function only accepts integer timestamps the u format character is only useful when using the date_format() function with user based timestamps created with date_create().

And note also that the fractional part format mask is `u`, not `U` (lower-case, not upper-case)

However, DateTime objects do support fractional seconds, so you can use:

```
$dto = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', '103.900');
echo $dto->format('i:s.u');
```